# Output text to kivy label in popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having a problem with getting the text from a method shown in a popup from a label I created inside the popup. All of my labels, buttons, layouts...etc are different classes so I dont know if it's a timing issue or a instance issue, but I want the popup to show the text from the label. I've got one button that calculates the logic, and then shows the popup all in the same method. I can get text to appear if I directly add underneath the label in my kv file OutputLabel: text: "whatever" but I cant if I just try to reference the label in the class and make the label's text property the output.

Main.py (at the end, I've got the output label and popup window being created)
class Calculate(Button):

```
class Calculate(Button):
    #main program
    def calculate(self):

        #make inputs into numbers
        goal = float(self.goal.text)
        save = float(self.save.text)
        savei = float(self.savei.text) / 100
        repeat = float(self.repeat.text)
        syears = int(self.syears.text)
        smonths = int(self.smonths.text)

        #get current compound toggle
        compound = 0
        if self.daily.state == 'down':
            compound = 365
        elif self.monthly.state == 'down':
            compound = 12
        elif self.yearly.state == 'down':
            compound = 1

        #get current repeat deposit toggle
        repDep = 0
        if self.none.state == 'down':
            repDep = 0
        elif self.week.state == 'down':
            repDep = 7
        elif self.biweek.state == 'down':
            repDep = 14
        elif self.month2.state == 'down':
            repDep = 30.417
        elif self.year2.state == 'down':
            repDep = 365

        #variables for program
        totalDays = syears*365 + smonths*30.417
        interestRate = savei/compound
        totalMoney = 0
        count = 0
        day = 0
        repDay = 0
        counter = 0

        #program begin
        while totalDays > 0:
            if count < 1:
                totalMoney = save
                totalDays -= 1
                count += 1
            totalDays -= 1
            if compound == 365:
                totalMoney *= (interestRate * repDep + 1)
                totalDays -= 1
            elif compound == 12:
                if day >= 30:
                    totalMoney *= (interestRate * repDep + 1)
                    day = 0
                    totalDays -= 1
                else:
                    day += 1
                    totalDays -= 1
            elif compound == 1:
                if day == 365:
                    totalMoney *= (interestRate * repDep + 1)
                    day = 0
                    totalDays -= 1
                else:
                    day += 1
                    totalDays -= 1
            if repDay >= repDep:
                totalMoney += repeat
                repDay = 0
            else:
                repDay += 1
        #final output string     
        total = str(totalMoney)


    #totals popup screen        
        out = OutputLabel()
        show = TotalPopup()
        popupWindow = Popup(title="TOTALS", content=show, size_hint=(.8,.8)) 
    # Create the popup window
        out.text = total
        popupWindow.open() # show the popup



    pass
```

Layout.kv (define the popup layout. If I write text: "whatever" in here it shows, but anything else says the attribute of my output is a nonetype to my outputlabel.text)

```
<TotalPopup>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        OutputLabel:
        GoalOutputLabel:
        NoReinvestLabel:
```

OutputLabel

> class OutputLabel(Label):
>       pass

Otherwise, it'll run right now just fine, it just wont show the text from the label in the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I figured something else out. Just wrote the label inside the popup creation code. But, I'd still like to know how to do it without having to do that, if there is a way.